# Facebook: Trying to post on a user's timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a webpage of a library which (after the user's permission) tries to post on the user's Facebook timeline by using PHP:

```
Karen is reading 'Fifty Shades of Grey'
A link to http://www.mylibrarysi.te/book.php?id=4048
```

I tried with this piece of code:

```
$out = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array(
'message' => "Karen is reading 'Fifty Shades of Grey'",
'name' => 'Fifty Shades of Grey',
'description' => "Description of 'Fifty Shades of Grey'",
'caption' => 'A book in your library',
'picture' => 'http://www.mylibrarysi.te/bookcover.php?id=4048',
'link' => 'http://www.mylibrarysi.te/book.php?id=4048',
));
```

I've two questions:

1) I've just read that Facebook started to stop this possibility to "improve the quality", deprecating "Authenticated referrals" and "Post to friends wall via the API"
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/

Can my piece of code be banned by Facebook to avoid spam? (users grant me to post on their timelines)

2) The result of my piece of code is

```
Karen Miller shared a link via MY_APP_NAME
Karen is reading 'Fifty Shades of Grey'
(the link, etc.)
```

is it possible to remove the "Karen Miller shared a link via MY_APP_NAME" text?

Thank you very much in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You are posting to your user wall, not your user's friends walls. So this should not affect you.

2) The only way to remove the `Karen Miller shared a link via MY_APP_NAME` text is if you turn your story as an Open Graph action. Read the [Open Graph tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/opengraph-tutorial/) to understand how to publish app-specific stories. This will allow you to create rich stories like the one shown in [Best Practices: Creating Open Graph Stories](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/creating-open-graph-stories/).

Note that there is a standard OG object [`book`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-objects/#book) that your application can use, so you can reuse it, no need to create your own object. This will also add the `book`s your app posts about to the list of books that all apps (like Kindle, Goodread, etc) have posted about.

Answer (score 1):

1) Facebook is deprecating the "post to friends wall" - you will not be able to post to the friend of a user. You are posting to the user wall , so this call will work. However, Facebook platform policies don't allow to post with a "message" that was not written by the user  inside your application, so you may have the publish privilege removed;

2) This is a link post because you are attaching a "link" to the post. You may refer to the link in the "message" and remove the link parameter. However, by doing this, Facebook won't show the link description with picture.

Comment: Hi Rafael. Thank you very much for your answer.


1)

Comment: Hi Rafael. Thank you very much for your answer.

1) I don't understand you. Is it possible to activate the "publish privilege" in any way?

2) I tried to leave only message + name parameters and, effectively,  it does not show the "shared a link" message.

Comment: I mean the "publish_stream" permission from the user, which you already have if you are able to publish messages to his wall. What you can't do anymore is to publish to a friend of your user.